# Set Up Realm Mobile Platform on Ubuntu (Digital Ocean)

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I just set up a new Ubuntu 16.04 Droplet on Digital Ocean and I'm following this tutorial to get a Realm Object Server running: https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/install-realm-object-server/

I have installed the service, but now I'm trying to figure out how to adjust my `configuration.yml`. Right now I have an IP address that points to `/var/www/html` on my server. I have changed all instances of `listen_address` in the `configuration.yml` file to my Droplet's IP address, but when I visit the IP address, it still shows the default landing page: http://d.pr/i/KznK

Is there more I am supposed to do either with Apache or with the Realm config to get it to point to the Realm Server's admin screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually hitting the Realm Object Server. This page looks like a default page for apache or something, on DigitalOcean. You need to specify the port of the server in order to reach it: `http://<ip>:9080` by default.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I am definitely not hitting the Realm server. I'm trying to figure out how to make my IP address route traffic to the server. I have tried adding the port to the IP address and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Am I actually supposed to change the `configuration.yml` IP addresses to my server's IP? Or should I leave them as `127.0.0.1` and do something else on the server that would route traffic from my IP to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Glad you got it working. I wrote the configuration file, and thought it was fairly explicit that by default, the server would bind to all addresses (the `127.0.0.1` is commented out by default). Feel free to suggest improvements in the RMP GitHub repo if you have any suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/7

Installing an Ubuntu Droplet without the LAMP stack worked without any changes to `configuration.yml`.